# File access from Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net

I using C# for making an app. I want to access pictures form user system by using that code.`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+ "//FolderName"`. It was working fine on windows 10. But if we use that code in windows 8.1. It will generate "unauthorizedaccessexception" of path.Kindly help me to get ride of that problem.

Comment: You dont have access to the folder on your windows 8 machine. Its a permissions problem. Open security permissions on the folder path and give access to your users.

Comment: Try this : string myDocuments = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\FolderName";

Comment: @MasterYoda I also get permissions for that folder but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you really use two *forward* slashes? I wonder that this worked at all. You  should use backslashes. Also, always use `System.IO.Path.Combine(...)` to construct paths. Your code will also fail (with forward *or* backward slashes after the `+`), if the part before the `+` already contains a backslash at the end. `System.IO.Path.Combine(...)` takes care of this.